# How can I move a new record form into a related records show page?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, activerecord

I have 2 tables: venues and reviews where 1 venue can have many reviews and a review belongs to a venue. I currently add the reviews to the venues from a link in the venue show page to the reviews new page:

**venues/show.html.erb**

```
<div class="button">
  <%= link_to 'Add a review', new_venue_review_path(@venue) %>
</div>
```

**reviews/new.html.erb**

```
<% form_for [@venue, @review] do |f| %>
  <p>title: <br>
  <%= f.text_field :title %></p>

  <%= submit_tag %>
<% end %>
```

**reviews controller**

```
  def new
    @review = Review.new
  end

  def create
    @review = Review.new params[:review]
    @review.venue = @venue
    if @review.save
      flash[:notice] = 'Review added'
      redirect_to venue_path(@venue)
    else
      render :action => :new
    end
  end
```

**venues controller**

```
class VenuesController < ApplicationController

  def index
    if
      @venues = Venue.with_type(params[:venuetypes]).with_area(params[:areas])
    else
      @venues = Venue.all
    end
  end

  def new
    @venue = Venue.new
  end

  def create
    @venue = Venue.new params[:venue]
    if @venue.save
      flash[:notice] = 'Venue added'
      redirect_to venues_path
    else
      render :action => :new
    end
  end

  def edit
    @venue = Venue.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
   @venue = Venue.find(params[:id])
   @venue.attributes = params[:venue]
   if @venue.save!
     flash[:notice] = 'Venue updated successfully'
     redirect_to venues_path(@venue)
   end
 end

 def show
   @venue = Venue.find(params[:id])
 end
end
```

**routes**

```
  resources :venues do
    resources :reviews
  end
end
```

How can I move the add new review form directly into the venues show page? Moving the code over gives a undefined method `model_name' for NilClass:Class error.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: What does the venues controller look like?

Comment: show your venue controller code too

Comment: @Ben Lee and @Paul Schreiber added, thanks for having a look.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add `@review = Review.new` to the show action on your venues controller. Then put the form right in your venue#show view file.

**venues_controller.rb**

```
def show
  @venue = Venue.find(params[:id])
  @review = Review.new
end
```